# Build cannot find [Test] method

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

After building  the script below, it does not return any error message. But the build does not find the `[Test]` method, so I cannot execute it. (I do have the packages but did not paste it here).

What can be missing?

```
public Prestador()
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
    options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    tiraScreenshot = new capturaImagem(driver);
    CPF = new geraCPF(driver);
    navegador = new acessaSite(driver);
    login = new Login(driver);
    sessao = new sair(driver);
    prestadores = new crudPrestador(driver);
    massa = new massaBase(driver);
}

public void AutomacaoPrestadores(massa.PageObjects.massaBase.DadosTXT coluna)
{
    AutomacaoPrestadores(coluna.usuarioLogin, coluna.senhaLogin, coluna.nomePrestador, coluna.emailPrestador);
}

[Test]
[TestCaseSource("ArquivoTXT")]
public void AutomacaoPrestadores(string usuarioLogin, string senhaLogin, string nomePrestador, string emailPrestador)
{
    navegador.acessaURL();
    login.fazLogin(usuarioLogin, senhaLogin);
    prestadores.acessaMenu();
    prestadores.novoCadastro(nomePrestador, emailPrestador);
    prestadores.pesquisaPrestador(nomePrestador, emailPrestador);
    prestadores.editaPrestador(nomePrestador, emailPrestador);
    prestadores.pesquisaPrestador(nomePrestador, emailPrestador);
    prestadores.inativaPrestador(nomePrestador);
    sessao.FazLogoff();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have the proper nunit packages installed? it sounds like a visual studio issue rather than a selenium issue.

Comment: Did you add `[TestClass]` attribute to the surrounding class?

Comment: @socalcheesehead Yes, I have the following packages installed: NUnit, 
NUnit Console Runner - Deprecated: Use NUnit.Console, NUnit Console Runner Version 3 Plus Extensions, NUnit Console Runner Version 3 (No Extensions), NUnit 3 Test Adapter for Visual Studio, NUnit Test Adapter for VS2012, VS2013 and VS2015, NUnit 3 - NUnit Project Loader Extension, NUnit 3 - NUnit V2 Framework Driver Extension, NUnit 3 - NUnit V2 Result Writer Extension, Selenium WebDriver, Selenium WebDriver Support Classes, Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.

Comment: @JeffC Did not use this attribute. Where does it goes on the script?

Comment: Above the `class`. You should probably take a look at the documentation. It will give you more details.

Comment: is your class marked as TestFixture ?

Comment: @socalcheesehead yes, it is.

Comment: @JeffC, here is the thing: I must be declaring something in the wrong place on the scripts, both at main and child classes. If I write all the code on the same class .cs, it does work, but breaking the code to do object orientation does not. The use of [TestClass] or similars will really fix it? maybe I can e-mail you or something, to show what I am doing.

Comment: were you able to get passed this issue?

Comment: Nope, still waiting some orientation about my OO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question finally solved, by the code below:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(massaBase), "ArquivoTXT")]
    public void AutomacaoPrestadores(massaBase.DadosTXT coluna)
```

Thanks everybody who wanted to help :)